# AzureSearchSDK returning diffrent results than portal test

Tags: azure, utf-8, azure-cognitive-search

While using SearchAsync function from AzureSearch .NET SDK putting in query encoded string containing UTF8 signs I got null response, no records are found. After investigation on Fiedler, I know that POST request is sent to azure search service:

url:
    /indexes('[INDEX_NAME]'/docs/search.post.search?api-version=2017-11-11 HTTP/1.1

body:

```
{
"count": false,
 "facets": [],
 "filter": "search.ismatch('6','CataloguesIds')",
 "queryType": "full",
 "scoringParameters": [],
 "search": "pier%C5%9Bcionek*",
 "searchMode": "any",
 "select": "Id,Name"
 }
```

The same request sent by Azure Portal returns proper results. Although Fiedler shows that method used in portal is GET

url: /indexes/products-index/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=pier%C5%9Bcionek*.

What should I do to get the same response from AzureSearch SDK as in portal for queries containing UTF8 signs? For request without UTF8 signs SearchAsync method returns proper results.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect results to be the same between the query explorer in the Azure Portal and using the API directly.

In this case, the two queries you included above are different. The POST query includes both a search clause and a filter clause, while the GET request only has search clause. Perhaps there are no documents in the index that satisfy both conditions formulated in the POST query, resulting in empty results?

Additionally, for the body of the POST request you should not URL-encode values. The body needs to be a proper JSON document (including accounting for the right character encoding) with no additional encoding.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, I finally figured it out it was not the matter of filtering, in dataset there were records match both (filtering and searching) criteria. To get proper results from POST you should not previously encode the query when using Polish Microsoft Analyzer. For example it should be _pierścionek_ instead of  _pier%C5%9Bcionek_

Comment: That's right, sorry I missed that from your original example, I'll add that to the answer to make it complete.